# Called Command window doesn't close in batch & powershell hybrid

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

***Edit*** *People are focusing on the program that was being called, however the issue occurs even on xcopy batches like the one below.*

```
c: 
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " $$a in ('date /t') do (set weekday=%%a& set day=%%b& set month=%%c& set year=%%d) 
set jdate=%day%-%month%-%year% 
g: 
md brd_backup_%jdate% 
cd brd_backup_%jdate% md data md programs 
f: 
cd\brdata 
xcopy d:\brdata\data*.* g:\brd_backup_%jdate%\brdata\data*.* /a /y /s 
xcopy d:\brdata\programs*.*
```

**Original Post Below:**

I replaced a server with a new Server 2012 R2 box.  The batch below is supposed to prompt for the store number then import the file to the software.  It worked fine for 6 years on the old server.  I copied the batch file to the new server and now the batch file will not close the CMD window when done.  This happens to ANY batch I construct, old ones or brand new ones.  I have read that I should begin my batch with START "" and then enclose my batch in quotes, however this did not work (I may have done it wrong).  How do I get the CMD windows to close automatically?  Why did they stop?  The answer below says that Powershell may help however I have no experience with Powershell and cannot get it to work.

```html
@echo off
set store= 01
set /p store= Which store would you like to import? (Two digits):

f:
cd\brdftp

::
::     Pulls Store
:::::::::::::::::::::::

cd\brdftp\store%store%


xcopy ir*.* f:\brdata
xcopy *.pdf /a /s /y f:\brdata\images\dsdefimg
del *.* /q


::                          imports files to brdata
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
f:
cd\brdata

start /w plbwin rftw9417 -auto
```

Comment: So the **plbwin** is another batch file, and that's the one that doesn't close properly? Or are you saying it's the calling batch file (i.e. the one you listed above)  that doesn't close after it's executed?

Comment: `plbwin` calls a program (brdata) that was created with the Sunbelt PL/B language.  the `plbwin` is the executable and the `rftw9417` is the specific program functon it is calling `-auto` is the switch to not wait for user input.  It is basically just importing the data files into the brdata program.  
Unfortunately any script will not close automatically whether the 'start /w' portion is included at any point or not.  Here is an example of another script that does the same thing: 
`f:
cd\brdftp\overstocks
move ov*.* f:\brdata
cd..
cd..
cd\brdata
plbwin posw9408`

Comment: Batch files don't act to close the command prompt windows they launched, the command prompt windows go away automagically when the program running inside them exits. This sounds like your real problem is "*plbwin.exe doesn't quit on Server 2012 r2*" ?

Comment: Same problem is typical when starting processes and services, since often they don't quit after start.

Comment: I have a different batch I use to back up some folders in one partition to a network drive that is doing the same thing.  Example below,  dates Tampa and copies files.  Example: c: for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " $$a in ('date /t') do (set weekday=%%a& set day=%%b& set month=%%c& set year=%%d) set jdate=%day%-%month%-%year% g: md brd_backup_%jdate% cd brd_backup_%jdate% md data md programs f: cd\brdata xcopy d:\brdata\data\*.* g:\brd_backup_%jdate%\brdata\data\*.* /a /y /s xcopy d:\brdata\programs\*.*

Answer (score 0):

Modify your original script to run:

```
start "" /b plbwin rftw9417 -auto
```

Alternatively, try:

```
call plbwin rftw9417 -auto
```

If the batch window still doesn't close, replace *fullpath* with the path to *plbwin.exe*, then run Powershell command from your batch to start a target program in a hidden window:

```
set "img=fullpath\plbwin.exe" & set "cfg=rftw9417 -auto"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden -FilePath '%img%'"^
 "-WorkingDirectory '%img:~0,-11%' -ArgumentList '-f ""%cfg%"""'}"
```

Comment: Neither function worked.  I created a batch file that simply pings www.google.com and that cmd window closes, but anything that calls an external program holds the cmd window open.  I have waited a week once and the cmd window still did not close.

Comment: @Aaron Martin I updated the answer. Test it, study and play with the Powershell command format if any errors. Post them here. It works great for me in the same scenario, when starting certain services in a hidden window.

Comment: For clarity, pls rename your question to: _Called Cmd window doesn't close on batch completion_.

Comment: Neither worked.  I created a batch file that simply pings www.google.com and that cmd window closes, however others don't even when not calling a program. Example:
`c:`
`for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " $$a in ('date /t') do (set weekday=%%a& set day=%%b& set month=%%c& set year=%%d)`
`set jdate=%day%-%month%-%year%`

`g:`
`md brd_backup_%jdate%`
`cd brd_backup_%jdate%`
`md data`
`md programs`

`f:`
`cd\brdata`
`xcopy d:\brdata\data\*.* g:\brd_backup_%jdate%\brdata\data\*.* /a /y /s`
`xcopy d:\brdata\programs\*.*` `g:\brd_backup_%jdate%\brdata\programs\*.* /a /y /s``

Comment: @Aaron Martin Did you read my updated _Answer_ above, not _Comment_. If Yes, did you try the Powershell method, posted in the answer? What was the output?

Comment: My page hadn't caught the update at the time I answered, I am trying powershell option now.  If this does work, will the process remain open yet hidden?  I would like to close out the process rather than just hide it as the server runs several batches per day.  Is there any negative side effect to the processes remaining open but hidden over the course of a month or two?  Will post powershell results shortly.

Comment: It works for me. Replace _fullpath_ with your path. Check _plbwin.exe_ process in Process Explorer or Task Manager. If running, add `taskkill /f /im yourTaskName.exe >nul 2>&1` in the batch.

Comment: When I run it (replacing fullpath with f:\brdata\plbwin.exe I get "the ampersand (&) character is not allowed. the & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks to pass it as part of a string.  I did that then I get A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'set'
In either case the second line requires me to press enter it does not complete (possibly because of the earlier error) but when I press enter it drops to a >> prompt.  Not too familiar with powershell, might be missing something obvious.

Comment: @Aaron Martin Try changing `'%img:~0,-10%'`, or `set cfg="rftw9417 -auto"`, play with double quotes number around %cfg%. Which ampersand? This code works perfect for me for awhile in Win10. Try using delayed expansion vars, if enabled with setlocal, like `!cfg!`. This type of Powershell task needs user own debugging skills, hard from distance. I use it, since 2nd Cmd window doesn't close upon calling an EXE.

Comment: Perhaps a Powershell solution is not the route for me to go, I have no experience and cannot debug.

Comment: @Aaron Martin If you rename your question to: `Called Command window doesn't close in batch & powershell hybrid`, add `Powershell` tag, and refer to this Powershell code and my answer in your question, other users may chime in. I don't believe, pure batch solution exists for this issue, since I researched it in the past.

Comment: @Aaron Martin Refer to my answer in your question, otherwise folks won't understand what hybrid you're talking about.

Comment: @Aaron Martin Forget to mention, since this Poweshell commands spans over 2 lines, make sure to put `space` at the start of 2nd line, as shown in my example. Also, the entire command should not end with `)` as often happens in IF and FOR loops, place them on the next line if any. Try also adding space before `^`, and removing it on the 2nd line start, its the line splitter.